# Dynamic values for asp control

Tags: asp.net, tags

I'd like have the following type of code fragment in a .aspx page:

```
<% foreach( int i in <some-expression> ) { %>
    <asp:linkbutton CommandArgument="<value-of-i>" OnClick="<some-handler>" runat="server" />
<$ } %>
```

Basically, I want to generate the page sans data binding, but supply the value of CommandArgument to the linkbutton from a variable in the code behind, so that when the click handler activates, I can retrieve the value of the variable from the CommandArgument, that existed when the code ran.

I do not want to use data binding, for various reasons.  Is this possible?  I understand that the <%: ... %> syntax is equivalent to Response.Write, and that the syntax <%# %> retrieves values which are databound.  I also know that I can't use the <%: %> syntax here to solve my problem.  And because I am not using data binding, I can't use the <%# %> syntax.

It seems to me that something like this should be very basic.

Comment: What if you generate this link button from code behind file and place it into placeholder ??

Comment: This is a possibility, but I would have to embed the placeholders (with the value of i, in this example), locate them in the code behind and construct a control from that with the extracted value of i.  It just seems that there should be a way to embed the value of i right in the page somehow.

Comment: You don't need to add placeholder in the for loop. Just add it in your page and from the code behind file execute your loop and generate link button and add it in placeholder. Or is it a nested for loop case ??

Comment: My example is very simplified here.  In the actual page I am working on, there is a lot of other tags and controls mixed in with the controls which have the values of i.  So, I'd rather not have to generate that part of the page from code behind as well.

Comment: I don't think so you can do it at least for asp.net control. Another approach would be generate html link with javascript function defined on it within your for loop and set the value of "i" in the parameter of that function like this - `<a href="#" onClick="myFunc('" + i + "')">Link1</a>` and then pass this value of i in code behind file using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question, there seems to be no way to mix server side controls and state generated from the code around them.  The reason being that server side controls are generated before the code runs, and the code, for the most part, runs to emit the response (think Response.Write).

However, one can "manually" cause the post back that server side controls, like asp:LinkButton, perform with a java script call to __doPostBack.  So the solution to my problem is something like the following:

```
<% for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { %>
        <a href="" onclick='javascript:__doPostBack( "MeClicked", "<%: i %>" ); return false; '>Click Me <%: i %></a>
<% } %>
```

Where Page_Load does something like::

```
if ("MeClicked".Equals( Request.Form[ "__EVENTTARGET" ] )) {
    string arg = Request.Form[ "__EVENTARGUMENT" ];
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Write( arg + " Clicked" );
    Response.End();
    return;
}
```